# biblatex citation style with no preceding "p." before page number

Tags: biblatex

I use the citation command `\cite[00X1]{stacksproject}`. This yields `[p. 00X1, SP]` but it should be `[00X1, SP]` as the optional argument is a tag not a page number.

Which biblatex argument do I have to use to disable the automatic addition of this "p. " in the beginning?

## Setup

My biblatex setup is

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=alphabetic
]{biblatex}
```

## Remarks/Attempts

I'm fine to disable it globally. I'm happy to use `\cite[p.~3]{...}` when I actually need page numbers.

I tried messing around with adding the following command, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkpageprefix[...][...]{#1}}
```

When using `\printbibliography`, it should still automatically print the page ranges there like `pp. 312-345`.

I'm sorry if that has already been answered, but I couldn't find it neither here nor in
[biblatex' documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), a link to a reference would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` has a heuristic to check if the `postnote` argument is a page (range), `00X1` passes that test because `biblatex` tries to allow for both Arabic and Roman numerals and `00X1` contains only characters allowed in Roman and Arabic numbers.

If you had written `00Y1`, you would not have seen a "p." in the output because `Y` can not be part of Roman or Arabic numbers.

You can help `biblatex` along and tell it explicitly that the postnote is not a page range with the command `\nopp`

```
Lorem \autocite[\nopp 00X1]{sigfridsson}
```

That will suppress any "p."/"pp." prefix.

If no citations of a particular work refer to page ranges, you can tell `biblatex` about that by adding the field `pagination` to the `.bib` entry with the value `none`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  pagination   = {none},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[\nopp 00X1]{sigfridsson} % suppress page prefix

Lorem \autocite[00X1]{sigfridsson} % passes "pages test"

Lorem \autocite[00Y1]{sigfridsson} % doesn't pass "pages test"

Lorem \autocite[00X1]{nussbaum} % pagination=none

Lorem \autocite[00Y1]{nussbaum} % pagination=none
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR98, 00X1]//Lorem [SR98, p. 00X1]//Lorem [SR98, 00Y1]//Lorem [Nus78, 00X1]//Lorem [Nus78, 00Y1]]

If you want to get rid of the pages prefix globally in all citations for all entries, use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

if you still want `biblatex` to parse and format number ranges, or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
```

if no such parsing and formatting should be done at all.

In any case you can manually add "p." or "pp." with `\pno` and `\ppno`

```
\autocite[\pno~380]{sigfridsson}
\autocite[\ppno~380-382]{sigfridsson}
```

should you so desire.

---

This is documented in §3.14.3 *Page Numbers in Citations* (p. 146-147 in v3.14) and §2.3.12 *Pagination* (p. 41 in v3.14) of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). But as always it is easier to find the relevant pages in the documentation if you know the answer already.

Comment: Thank you! `pagination={none}` is even a better solution than I hoped for. And thank you for the reference to the doc.