How do I get rid of "pp." when referencing in Harvard with biblatex?
I use Harvard references. Instead of (Smith 2000: pp. 10-12), I would like to generate (Smith 2000: 10-12). I use the following code:
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=unified, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=99, natbib]{biblatex}

How can I get rid of the "pp."?

Please add a minimal working example, from \documentclass to \end{document}

The classic way to remove "p."/"pp." from citation postnotes is by redefining the relevant field formats.
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=unified, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380-382]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537263/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633404/35864

You can redefine the labels for whichever language(s) you need. For example,
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page                  =       {},
  pages                 =       {},
}

Either add this to your preamble (for a particular document) or put it in biblatex.cfg (for a personal default) and put that file somewhere LaTeX can find it e.g. into TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/config/ where TEXMFHOME is your personal TeX tree.
